# SQL REDDIT - Jaccard Similarity

Tags: sql, comments, google-bigquery, reddit

I am trying to implement a fancy SQL query but am having trouble with trying to execute the join and count.

I have a very long table of data :

```
author | group | id |

daniel | group1| 118
adam   | group2| 126
harry  | group1| 221
daniel | group2| 323
daniel | group2| 122
daniel | group5| 322
harry  | group1| 222 
harry  | group1| 225
```

...
...

I want my output to look like:

```
author1 | author2 | intersection | union

daniel | adam | 2 | 3
daniel | harry| 2 | 11
adam   | harry| 0 | 10
```

where intersection is defined as the # of groups where author1 & author2 have in common, and union = # of groups author1 + author - intersection.

I think the proper way to do this is by

table a left join b table on a.group == b.group

but i can't figure out how to do the aggregate count.

Thanks `enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

“Jumping In” because 1) still don't see any answer 2) saw author's related question with BigQuery Tag

So, theoretically, below query would make your task (using bigquery-samples.reddit.full table for below examples):

BigQuery Legacy SQL:

```
SELECT
  a.author AS author1, 
  b.author AS author2, 
  SUM(a.subr = b.subr) AS count_intersection,
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(a.subr) + EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(b.subr) - SUM(a.subr = b.subr) AS count_union
FROM 
  (SELECT author, subr FROM [bigquery-samples:reddit.full] GROUP BY 1, 2) AS a
CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT author, subr FROM [bigquery-samples:reddit.full] GROUP BY 1, 2) AS b
WHERE a.author < b.author
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY count_intersection DESC
LIMIT 100
```

BigQuery Standard SQL:

```
WITH subrs AS (
  SELECT author, subr 
  FROM `bigquery-samples.reddit.full` 
  GROUP BY 1, 2
)
SELECT
  a.author AS author1, 
  b.author AS author2, 
  COUNTIF(a.subr = b.subr) AS count_intersection,
  COUNT(DISTINCT a.subr) + COUNT(DISTINCT b.subr) - COUNTIF(a.subr = b.subr) AS count_union
FROM subrs AS a 
JOIN subrs AS b
ON a.author < b.author
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY count_intersection DESC
LIMIT 100
```

If you will try to run them, you most likely to get below error

> An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed

The reason is because each of those two queries produces about trillion rows as a result of join (see below stats).
There are many ways to address this – below proposed way is to address this by tuning requirements.
Do you really need to involved into algorithms light authors with let’s say just one or two subreddits?
Or – do you really want to find similarity between those who have just very few comments in specific subreddits?

See below, how introducing extra limits helps in executing above queries (note: `lines` is min limit count of entries per author per subr and `subrs` is min limit of number of subr per user)

[image]

Below is version that actually produces result w/o any type of failure:

Standard SQL

```
WITH authors AS (
  SELECT author FROM (
    SELECT author, COUNT(1) AS subrs FROM (
      SELECT author, subr, COUNT(1) AS lines 
      FROM `bigquery-samples.reddit.full` 
      GROUP BY 1, 2
      HAVING lines > 1
    ) 
    GROUP BY author
    HAVING subrs > 3
  )
),
subrs AS (
  SELECT author, subr 
  FROM `bigquery-samples.reddit.full` 
  WHERE author IN (SELECT author FROM authors)
  GROUP BY 1, 2
)
SELECT
  a.author AS author1, 
  b.author AS author2, 
  COUNTIF(a.subr = b.subr) AS count_intersection,
  COUNT(DISTINCT a.subr) + COUNT(DISTINCT b.subr) - COUNTIF(a.subr = b.subr) AS count_union
FROM subrs AS a JOIN subrs AS b
ON a.author < b.author
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY count_intersection DESC
LIMIT 100
```

In similar way you can adjust Legacy SQL to make it work

This might be not the best way - but at least gives some hope on such tasks to be able to easily run within BigQuery, w/o going to other workarounds

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.jaccard_similarity(IN vector anyarray)
    RETURNS double precision[]
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN(select ARRAY(
            select(
                select (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select vector1 INTERSECT select vector2) as intersect_elements)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(select vector1 UNION select vector2) as union_elements) from unnest($1,"TOPIC_VECTOR") as t(vector1,vector2)) 
            from public.tbl_topic) 
            as score);

END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.jaccard_similarity(anyarray)
    OWNER TO postgres;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION public.jaccard_similarity(anyarray)
    IS 'this function is used for calculating a jaccard similarity of input vector with all vector in databse.';
```

one can use this function for referenenec.
Thank you.